# Masses and Pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I have a two mass and a pulley system as shown here: [image]

I have the following two questions:

First, why does $\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} y_p$ is not zero, i I mean I don't understand why does $ y_p$ is going to change over time (it's a constant, right?).

Second, and why does $\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} y_p = A$? (A is defined as the acceleration upward of the pulley)

Comment: Ok I get it now, so if anyone have the same question, the answers are:

First, the problem is telling you that the pulley is going up in an uniform acceleration motion. (I was getting confused, because I thought that A was: how fast is the pulley was rotating)

Second, now it does make sense that the second derivative of $ y_p  = A$

Answer (score 0):

The question says the pulley is accelerating upward at $A$.  This is the first sentence in what you have shown.